# Moving rectangle is not moving according to coordinates given

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a picturebox with a picture as a background (infact a map), and on it I am spawning rectangles. These rectangles are supposed to move by given points. The rectangle is moving with assigned speed, and after reaching (or getting close) to one of the points, it starts moving to the next one.  My problem however is, the rectangle doesnt move directly to the given point, it is just proceeding to get close to only one of the coordinates, so there are situations where the Y coordinate of the rectangle, and the Y coordinate of the point are the same, but the rectangle is like 60 pixels of and wont move.
Below I am adding a picture as an example of the movement. Blue is expected route, red is the actual one. I have checked the coordinates like a hundred times, they are correct, the rectangle is just moving elsewhere. Note: this only happens at some of the points.

[image]

Here is the code I am using to count the movement of the rectangle relative to axis X and Y.

```
public void Move_calculate(Graphics g)
    {
        if (points[passed].X == 0 || points[passed].Y == 0) // this happens when the rectangle reaches it final point - it stays where it is (working fine)
        {
            Redraw(g);
            return;
        }
        speed = randomNumbers.Next(7, 13);
        if (points[passed].X > x_coordinate && points[passed].Y > y_coordinate)
        {
            Bx = points[passed].X;
            By = points[passed].Y;
            distanceForAlfaX = Bx - x_coordinate; // x_coordinate is the x coordinate of the rectangle
            distanceForAlfaY = By - y_coordinate;
            if (distanceForAlfaX <= 20 || distanceForAlfaY <= 20) speed = 5; // slowing down when approaching the point
            if (distanceForAlfaX + distanceForAlfaY <= 15) passed += 1;
            alpha = (distanceForAlfaY / distanceForAlfaX); // tangent alpha
            x_change = (int)(speed * (Math.Cos(alpha))); // get distance moved relative to axis X
            y_change = (int)Math.Sqrt(((speed * speed) + (x_change * x_change))); // again distance for axis Y, using Pythagoras theorem
            x_coordinate += x_change;
            y_coordinate += y_change;
        }
        else if (points[passed].X > x_coordinate && points[passed].Y < y_coordinate)
        {
            Bx = points[passed].X;
            By = points[passed].Y;
            distanceForAlfaX = Bx - x_coordinate;
            distanceForAlfaY = y_coordinate - By;
            if (distanceForAlfaX <= 20 || distanceForAlfaY <= 20) speed = 5;
            if (distanceForAlfaX + distanceForAlfaY <= 15) passed += 1;
            alpha = (distanceForAlfaY / distanceForAlfaX);
            x_change = (int)(speed * (Math.Cos(alpha)));
            y_change = (int)Math.Sqrt(((speed * speed) + (x_change * x_change)));
            x_coordinate += x_change;
            y_coordinate -= y_change;
        }
        else if (points[passed].X < x_coordinate && points[passed].Y > y_coordinate)
        {
            Bx = points[passed].X;
            By = points[passed].Y;
            distanceForAlfaX = x_coordinate - Bx;
            distanceForAlfaY = By - y_coordinate;
            if (distanceForAlfaX <= 20 || distanceForAlfaY <= 20) speed = 5;
            if (distanceForAlfaX+distanceForAlfaY <= 15) passed += 1;
            alpha = (distanceForAlfaY / distanceForAlfaX);
            x_change = (int)(speed * (Math.Cos(alpha)));
            y_change = (int)Math.Sqrt(((speed * speed) + (x_change * x_change)));
            x_coordinate -= x_change;
            y_coordinate += y_change;
        }
        else if (points[passed].X < x_coordinate && points[passed].Y < y_coordinate)
        {
            Bx = points[passed].X;
            By = points[passed].Y;
            distanceForAlfaX = x_coordinate - Bx;
            distanceForAlfaY = y_coordinate - By;
            if (distanceForAlfaX <= 20 || distanceForAlfaY <= 20) speed = 5;
            if (distanceForAlfaX + distanceForAlfaY <= 15) passed += 1;
            alpha = (distanceForAlfaY / distanceForAlfaX);
            x_change = (int)(speed * (Math.Cos(alpha)));
            y_change = (int)Math.Sqrt(((speed * speed) + (x_change * x_change)));
            x_coordinate -= x_change;
            y_coordinate -= y_change;
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Something went wrong"); // just notify me that it isnt working again..
        }
        Pen p = new Pen(Color.Turquoise, 2);
        r = new Rectangle(x_coordinate, y_coordinate, 5, 5); // redraw the rectangle
        g.DrawRectangle(p, r);
        p.Dispose();
    }
```

I have no idea why this is happening, could anyone help with this?
P.S.
There is absolutely no need for the movement to be smooth, the positions of rectangles will be updated once per two seconds using a Timer. For now it is temporarily set to a button.

EDIT:
Here is the foreach code. The labels are just the coordinates shown next to the PictureBox

```
                     foreach (aircraft acft in aircrafts) // aircraft is an array aircrafts[]
                {
                        label2.Text = "xp" + acft.points[acft.passed].X;
                        label3.Text = "yp" + acft.points[acft.passed].Y;
                        label4.Text = acft.passed.ToString();
                        label5.Text = "y" + acft.y_coordinate.ToString();
                        //MessageBox.Show(acft.points[0].X.ToString());
                        acft.Move_calculate(e.Graphics);
                        spawn = string.Empty;
                    }
```

EDIT2: All variables in `aircraft` class

```
        public string callsign;
    public int speed;
    public double heading;
    public bool moving = false;
    public Point[] points;
    public double alpha;
    public int x_change;
    public int y_change;
    public int x_coordinate;
    public int y_coordinate;
    public int Bx;
    public int By;
    public double distanceForAlfaX;
    public double distanceForAlfaY;
    public int passed = 0;
    public Rectangle r;
```

Comment: To check the coordinates, next to the PictureBox I am also displaying current coordinates, points passed and coordinates of next point. When the rectangle acts like reaching the final point, it usually is totally elsewhere..
If needed, I can share the whole code, now about 300 lines long.

Comment: is this method being called in a loop or something? what else is triggering the points to move once it gets to a certain spot / point..? looks like you are missing some relevant code..

Comment: This method is called from PictureBox1.Paint in a foreach loop (for each of the rectangles). The PictureBox1.Paint is triggered after clicking the button (the button invalidates the PictureBox)

Comment: you should show the foreach loop code it would help to see what you are doing in that loop. also I've noticed that you are `Unregistering Events with the `x_coordinate -= x_change;` ...etc could one of those be causing the issue..

Comment: There is a ton of needless code duplication in the 'if' blocks. Consider refactoring this to remove the duplication and you'll be more likely to find your bug as well as avoid future bugs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, there's a math mistake in

```
y_change = (int)Math.Sqrt(((speed * speed) + (x_change * x_change)));
```

Moreover...

```
// again distance for axis Y, using Pythagoras theorem
```

Let Mr.Pythagoras be, I would rather use the same as for X axis

```
y_change = (int)(speed * (Math.Sin(alpha)));
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked your coordinate system? (https://web.archive.org/web/20140710074441/http://bobpowell.net/coordinatesystems.aspx)

Sorry, wrong link for your issue. Try debugging using Control.PointToClient to make sure all coordinates are expressed in client space. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.pointtoclient)

You could try:

```
    Point cPoint = this.PointToClient(new Point(x_coordinate, y_coordinate));
    Size cSize = new Size(5,5);
    r = new Rectangle(cPoint, cSize); // redraw the rectangle
    g.DrawRectangle(p, r);
```

Could you post the data types of your variables to clarify your code?  You might be losing precision somewhere, especially if you're using integer division.

(Note for DJ KRAZE, a -= b; in C# can also mean a = a - b;  Context matters.)

Comment: The `PointToClient` doesnt exist, what do I need to include?
as for the data types, all varibles in the `aircraft` class:
     ` public string callsign;
      public int speed;
      public double heading;
      public bool moving = false;
      public Point[] points;
      public double alpha;
      public int x_change;
      public int y_change;
      public int x_coordinate;
        public int y_coordinate;
        public int Bx;
        public int By;
        public double distanceForAlfaX;
        public double distanceForAlfaY;
        public int passed = 0;
        public Rectangle r;`

Comment: Hugh, that formatting is terrible. Will add it to the question itself..
For the precision - I am converting something to int, so of course it wont be exactly precise, but not this much

Comment: PointToClient is a Control method, so it should be present in your Form.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.pointtoclient.aspx for details.  Sorry I didn't get back to you sooner, and I'm glad to see you got your answer.  Cumulative error can really throw things off if you're repeatedly losing information.  For example, integer division of 10/3 = 3.  And (float)(10/3) = 3.0, but ((float)10)/((float)3) gives the expected results, albeit still with some tiny loss of precision.